# Outlook vba open code window when trigger rules on logged out Windows Server 2016

Tags: vba, windows, server, outlook

I have Windows server 2016. set up rules on Outlook for specific email Subject to save attachment upon receive into specific folder and upload the attachment data into AS400 database. The rules and code is working fine but the problem is when email received the rules apply during server log off, the VBA code windows will left open. However the program is still running fine. The only problem for me is VBA code windows left open when rules trigger during Windows Server Logged off.

Answer (score 0):

Keep running Outlook on the server side is not really a good idea. If you deal with Exchange profiles only you may consider developing a gateway for processing incoming emails instead. Outlook is a client-side application and designed running by a user. Here is what MS states for such scenarious:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.